# How to fix "File does not exist" error after adding ignore route for favicon

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, autofac, mvcextensions

I am using `ASP.NET MVC 3`.  I am also using `Autofac` and `MVC Extensions`.  The error that I initally got was:

```
The controller for path '/favicon.ico' was not found or does not implement IController.
```

I read a couple of posts and they all recommended that I put in the following:

```
Routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });
```

Then I started to get the following error:

```
File does not exist.
ExceptionType:HttpException Stacktrace:
     at System.Web.StaticFileHandler.GetFileInfo(String virtualPathWithPathInfo, String physicalPath, HttpResponse response)
     at System.Web.StaticFileHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContext context, String overrideVirtualPath)
     at System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
     at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

The error isn't telling me much as I don't know what what file it is trying to open up? How would I resolve this issue? I'm not using a favicon, I don't want one. I am using `Internet Explorer 8`.

Comment: The error suggests that the favicon doesn't exists in the location where it is being search for (the ignore route certainly works because StaticFileHandler has picked up the request).

Try using `Url.Content` in order to generate proper path to favicon and check if the error is still there.

There might be other reasons so I'm not posting this as an answer yet.

Comment: I'm not using a favicon.

Comment: Browsers automatically check if a website has a favicon, so you will (almost) always get a `GET` request for one, no matter if your application has a favicon or not. The MVC engine is then of course trying to process this request.

Comment: So you are fighting with Google Chrome’s blind request for favicon - sorry I didn't understood the question correctly.

Comment: I don't have a favicon and I don't want one, but it is looking for one. I am using IE8, not Chrome.

Comment: @BrendanVogt Where you are seeing this exception? ELMAH?

Comment: @BrendanVogt I have updated answer with detailed explanation and some possible workarounds.

Answer (score 2):

The request for favicon.ico is being blindly made by most modern browsers and they are expecting a *404 (File Not Found)* if there is no favicon (this is proper behaviour). Below you can find a quote from HTML5 working draft regarding [Link type "icon"](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/links.html#rel-icon)
:

> In the absence of a link with the icon keyword, for documents obtained
>   over HTTP or HTTPS, user agents may instead attempt to fetch and use
>   an icon with the absolute URL obtained by resolving the URL
>   /favicon.ico against the document’s address, as if the page had
>   declared that icon using the icon keyword.

The reason why you see the exception is that the web development server or IIS configured to use *Managed/Integrated Pipeline Mode* puts all requests through *Global.asax* (including errors).

You can try to prevent the browsers from making the requests by creating following dummy link to favicon:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#" />
        ...
    </head>
...
</html>
```

You can also create yourself an empty file for favicon or filter out the errors by checking `HttpException.GetHttpCode()` for *404* and `((System.Web.HttpApplication)Sender).Context.Request.Url` for */favicon.ico*.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a `favicon` in your site but still you want to get rid of this errors, you could create a file of size 0 bytes and name it as `favicon.ico`.

Answer (score 0):

alternative rule to try is just plain and simple:

```
// add ignore route for favicon.ico
routes.IgnoreRoute("favicon.ico");
```